# Facebook Messanger display issue on Android 5.1

Tags: android, facebook, messenger

Since upgrading my OS to Android 5.1, this happens all the time in Facebook Messenger app: the cells practically disappear, remaining only a part of each one.

Does anyone have the same problem? 
Do you know any solutions to this issue?
It's really annoying when you try to type. It comes back to normal if you scroll, but then it reappears.

Thanks 
[image: Facebook Messenger issue]

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently updated your device, but not **Facebook Messenger** then you'll have to delete cache/data (simply reinstalling it should solve your problems).

When Android redraws your activity it uses cached files, so clear cache should clear broken files.

Comment: What "clear broken files"? This happens even when I'm writing new messages. I believe that blue background is a 9patch drawable that they use. I don't think this ought to solve it, but I will give it a shot.